# CUDA copying array from device to host using cudaMemcpy2D

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

`cudaMemcpy2D` doesn't copy that I expected. After I read the manual about [cudaMallocPitch](http://horacio9573.no-ip.org/cuda/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db.html), I try to make some code to understand what's going on. But, well, I got a problem.

I made simple program like this:

```
int main()
{
    double *d_A;
    size_t d_pitch;

    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_A, &d_pitch, sizeof(double) * SIZE, SIZE);

    dim3 blocks(4, 4);
    dim3 threads(16, 16);

    doStuff<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_A, d_pitch);

    double *A;
    size_t pitch = sizeof(double) * SIZE;

    A = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * SIZE * SIZE);

    cudaMemcpy2D(A, pitch, d_A, d_pitch, sizeof(double) * SIZE, SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) printf("%f ", A[sizeof(double) * i + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and `doStuff` is:

```
__global__ void doStuff(double *d_A, size_t d_pitch)
{
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    double *target = ( (double*)(((char*)d_A) + (d_pitch * i)) ) + j;

    if (i < SIZE && j < SIZE)
        *target = (i + 1) * (j + 1) + 0.0;
}
```

So `doStuff` is same as `d_A[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1)`. If `SIZE` is 5, what I expected is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

in double precision. However, when I compile and run, I got:

```
1 2 3 4 5
8 10 3 6 9
8 12 16 20 5
25 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

It seems that for each row, `cudaMemcpy2D` overrides previous data. I try to find the problem changing pitch and widths, but I can't.

So what's going on my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) printf("%f ", A[sizeof(double) * i + j]);
```

It should be:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) printf("%f ", A[SIZE * i + j]);
```

You want to scale the row index (`i`) by the size of a row in elements (not the size of an element in bytes).

This has nothing to do with CUDA of course.

Comment: Wow... How embarassing :( You're right. Actually I still have a problem, but It's not concerned with this problem, so I rather ask again. Thank you for notice my mistake :D